# DVI Output over Thunderbolt only works after Reboot

Tags: macos, mac, multiple-monitors, dvi, thunderbolt

On my MacBook Pro the external monitor (connected via Thunderbolt) wont work (i.e. its continuosly switching between on and off) when connected via hotplug to a running device.

Only after I reboot the Mac it works.

Since I usually don`t reboot the mac this is really annoying.

Is there a way to fix this issue or work around is?

The goal is to be able to hot-plug an external monitor to my Mac w/o rebooting.